# How to call woocommerce product title in html?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to overylay woocommerce product title on its featured image, as i replaced featured image with some plane colored background and on it i need to call woocommerce product title. Please share how can i achieve this ?

```html
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   $html  = '<div data-thumb="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'shop_thumbnail' ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_size_image[0] ) . '">';
   $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_single', $attributes );
   $html .= '</a></div>';
  } else {
   $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
   $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src() ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
   $html .= '<div class="centered">';
      $html .=  how to call here!!!
   $html .= '</div>';
   $html .= '</div>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the product title from the product like this:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

$title = get_the_title($product->ID);
```

So your code becomes :

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $html  = '<div data-thumb="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'shop_thumbnail' ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_size_image[0] ) . '">';
            $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_single', $attributes );
            $html .= '</a></div>';
} else {
            $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

            $title = get_the_title($product->ID);
            $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
            $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src() ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
            $html .= '<div class="centered">';
            $html .=  $title ;
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
}
```

An edit :

Since you are within the loop, you do not need to get the product using the function I used. You can just use the global $product variable if the post is a product.